# check if a number @num is between val 1 and val2 of a row T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to write a T-SQL script that check if a number `@num` is between `val1` and `val2` of a row in below table:

```
tblIntervals

 id  val1   val2   points
 1   0.1    0.5    1
 2   0.6    0.7    2
 3   0.8    1      3
 4   1.1    1.3    4
 5   1.5    1.7    5
 ..  ....   ....   ....
```

For example: `If @num=0.3 then points=1`; `if @num=1.2 then points=4` 
Here is my piece of code which is not functional:

```
declare @num float
set @num = 0.5

select * from tblIntervals 
where @num between 

DECLARE @String NVARCHAR(2)
DECLARE @c NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @ID INT
WHILE EXISTS (select * from tblIntervals )
 BEGIN 
      WHILE LEN(@c) > 0
        BEGIN
           -- code
        END
 END
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tblIntervals WHERE @num BETWEEN val1 AND val2`?

Comment: yes, and this query does that?

Comment: I'm afraid it does!

Comment: `it does not`, why?, how?, what do you actually want?. I get that you are a newbie in t-sql, but that doesn't mean that you can't explain your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
SELECT points
FROM tblIntervals
WHERE @num BETWEEN val1 AND val2
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what this query does. What are you missing?

Comment: @DavidG Exactly what I just asked too

Comment: @Lamak it seems so well what?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tblIntervals WHERE @num>val1 AND @num<val2;
```